# Can I share a text file via a ShareAction without writing to disk?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream, shareactionprovider

I want to dynamically create a text file (.txt) object to share plaintext via a ShareAction but I want to keep the whole file object in memory - I don't want to write anything to disk. Is this a job for a BufferedOutputStream? A MemoryFile perhaps? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's no need to do this - Dropbox and Drive are both smart enough to know to save text/plain input as a .txt file. You're even prompted to choose a filename when you choose where to save it.